# how can tether a token to the price?

Tags: blockchain

Is there a function?
I think the token should be central.
Let's say that I have two tanks of water! And let's call one A and the other B.

So A is out of my control and refuels itself automatically, whenever! High and low, in and out etc .. without me getting involved.

B is going to be under my control and I will know everything about it, and it's going to be connected and exactly linked with A. So whatever is going to happen or change with A, B will do the same, and change at the same time but under my control.
Where do I find this contract if it exists?

Answer (score 1):

If you think carefully about what you’re saying, it doesn’t make sense. If A is out of your control, but dependent on B, it is not out of your control.  Is that not obvious?  Maybe I’m missing something.

Comment: "A" It's out of my control, let's say "bitcoin"
"B" It's under control "mytoken"
I want to Relate "B" with "A" to be the same price.

Comment: Assuming that "A"or bitcoin is =1$